# How to run an svn server on a Mac completely fire-walled from the outside?

Tags: svn, apache-2.2, mac-osx

Is there are way to run a local svn server on a Mac (OS X 10.6.x) such that no ports are open and accessible from outside that Mac?

If so, exactly where do any configuration scripts of any kind need to go?

Comment: Why bother?  If your goal a personal source repository, there are vastly better and easier to configure decentralized options.  Mercurial, git, Fossil, monotone, ...

Comment: So how do I migrate this question to programmers.stackexchange, if that's the more suitable QA forum?  (But a search showed more svn questions here than there.)

Comment: By "outside" do you mean outside that computer, or outside the network?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use subversion repositories with the file protocol tool, something like `file:///opt/svn/my_repo`. That way, you can use your SVN repos locally without the need for an actual server.

Another alternative could be to setup an Apache with mod_dav_svn and let it listen only to localhost (127.0.0.1).

Answer (score 0):

I think that by default when you install SVN it is only accessible from the local box as it does not have a built in networking infrastructure. You usually have to tie it into an apache config or tunnel to the box with SSH.

So you should be able to install it without a worry of networking. If your install automagically installs the apache piece, you should be able to disable it in your apache conf.

Comment: You would want to use the commandline interface at this point which is really easy to use.